# Adding External Context in Websphere Application Server

Tags: tomcat, websphere

I'm new to Websphere Application Server and I've a web application hosted on Apache Tomcat Server 8.X. In my Apache Tomcat Server, I've defined a context in server.xml as:

```
<Context docBase="/home/centos/clientFiles/myApp" path="/myAppFiles" reloadable="true"/>
```

Which means whenever I write

```
http://localhost:8080/myAppFiles
```

on browser, I'm served files from

```
/home/centos/clientFiles/myApp
```

Now I want to achieve the same functionality in Websphere Application Server and I really do not have any idea on how to achieve this.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an IBM HTTP Server in front of WebSphere Application Server? This is a very common topology. If so, you can serve static files from that  native server (non-jvm) using a `<Directory>` directive in `httpd.conf`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extended document root is probably what you are looking for (I'm assuming you want to serve html/jsp pages from there).

You will have to create `ibm-web.ext.xml` file with the following entries and maybe some other properties:

```
<file-serving-attribute name="extendedDocumentRoot" value="/yourpath/to/files" />
<jsp-attribute name="extendedDocumentRoot" value="/yourpath/to/files" />
```

Check [Web container configuration for JavaServer Pages static file access](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rweb_jsp_staticfile.html?lang=en) for more details.